# Optimisation of coefficient to minimise the error between a predicted dataset and an verify dataset

Tags: python, r, optimization, libgee

I'm trying to use the Nasa OC3 algorithm to compute chlorophyll-a concentration with the Landsat 8 satellite.
The equation is as follow : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmRNU.png)
Here the a0 -> a4 coefficient are the following :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgmf2.png)
And the X are a band ratio dataset.
So my goal here is to optimise those coefficients with the verify data so that the global error between the two dataset is minimized.
The two dataset are .csv documents so I can either use them with Python or Rstudio

I tried the aplore3 library but did not succeed to do what I wanted

Comment: Hi Aurélien. We don't have any of your data, and can't see what your variables are called. We don't know how you loaded the file or what format it is in after you imported it. That means we can't give you any code that might resolve your problem. We don't know what code you used, so we can't know why it didn't work. Could you perhaps [edit] the question to give us enough information to help you? Otherwise, I'm not sure what kind of answer you are looking for. Thanks.